# Why is my interval not working? (With firebase)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I stuck in a problem by coding on a javascript webapp with firebase:

```
function start() {
  setInterval(getComps, 2000);
}

function getComps() {
permis=true;
  for (var pc=policeNum; pc>0; pc--) {
    policeRef.child(pc).once('value', function(snapshot) {
      var oldData = snapshot.val();
      //KI:
      var compX=newX-oldData.X;
      var compY=newY-oldData.Y;
      updatePosition(compX, compY);
    });
  }
}
```

(The real code of the app is of course more complicated but this is enough to understand the problem I think) (The start() is called with a button in my index.html)

When I run my app I can see that updatePosition() is only called once in the beginning but not later again in my wanted interval. Do someone know what´s wrong here and can give me a example or explanation of a better code.

Thank you for every answer, I hope you can understand what I mean. (all variables are of course defined)

Comment: Where is the start function called?

Comment: @DoctorMick With a button in my index.html

Comment: Try using on() instead of once(). See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/once.html: "Listens for exactly one event of the specified event type, and then stops listening."